# Magento 2 Developer Certification Exam?

Tags: magento2, certification

Hope anyone can advise me on how I can prepare for the **Magento 2 Developer Certification Exam**?

Answer (score 0):

Take the test a few weeks ago and it is a very personalized test in which you have to show that you really have a job with Magento. You can study and have things clear, but many questions for practical cases. Magento's advice is to have worked the year and a half with the platform. Here you can find a guide and practice test. https://swiftotter.com/technical/certifications The exam questions do not look like the practice test, but you can know your level more or less.